# Windows phone 7: Other ways to remind the user of an event then alarm?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

Im making a medreminder app in windows 7. I want to send alert to user in case he misses to take medicine.
For that i have used alarm to alert user.

But i want user to get alert by either automatic sms or email to be send,which i seems not possible from code,because a popup appears and until user presses send,mail or sms doesnt go.

So my question is,apart from alarm,what are the possible ways to alert the user from phone itself.

I have searched on http://thesociablegeek.com/windows-phone-7/windows-phone-alerts-and-reminders/

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly that you wish to send an SMS from the user's phone to the phone itself?

Comment: User will enter email id and phone number of his friend while he sets alarm.And if he forgets to take pill,alarm should be ring and sms and mail should be sent automatically to his friend to remind him.

Comment: How will you know if the friend has forgotten to take the pill?

Comment: Ok now I understand. I believe that there's no direct way of sending the SMS without the user's consent so calling a webservice that sends the SMS I believe would be the workaround...

Comment: ok i need to search..how to do with webservice..Thanks..Pls forward if you have any links regarding webservice..

Comment: A quick search turned up this result which might help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg241261.aspx

Comment: Thanks..Will see to it..

Answer (score 1):

You can't send an SMS directly from the program, you can only compose a message but the user would still have to click "Send". The same applies to sending an email.

You can use an existing (or set up your own one) web service to do both of those things for you and just call the service from your wp7 app.

If it's just alerts you want though, I had good success implementing my alerts through Twitter using [TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp#using-windows-phone-7) . The app would post a little note under a set up twitter account and the guy receiving the alerts can subscribe to that account and have the alerts pushed to him with minimal latency. The functionality doesn't require any user activity (like clicking "send") and can even be fired from a background task.